# Probability Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability

> If $A$ is uniformly distributed over $[-25, 30]$, what is the probability that the roots of the equation
>   $$x^2 + Ax + A + 80 = 0$$
>   are both real?

I kept getting weird answers which was  wrong. $$A (1 + x)+ x^2+ 80 = 0$$
                                                $$A (1 + x)  = 0$$
                                                $$A =0 $$ $$x=-1$$
                                                $$ x^2+80 = 0 $$
                                                $$ x=-4i √(5) $$
                                                $$ x= 4i √(5) $$
I am so sure this approach to the question is incorrect. because it shouldn't have any sort of imaginary answers.

Comment: For wich values of $A$ are the roots real? Answering that helps you further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The roots are real if and only if $$A^2 - 4(A+80) \geq 0$$ by the quadratic formula.

Comment: A^2-4A-320>0. (A-20)(A+16)>0. (-inf,-16)(20,inf).

Comment: P(AUB)=P(A)+P(B)-P(AB). P(-25<A<-16)+P(20<A<30).

Comment: ∫ (1/55)dx= -16/55 + 25/55 = 9/55

Comment: Thank you very much for the help TOM and apt1002 . I didn't even know how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Applying the quadratic formula to the equation, we get:

$$x = -A +-\sqrt{A^2 - 4(A+80)}$$

So the question is, what is the probability that $A^2 - 4(A+80)$ is non-negative?